# How to set the width and height of the output image in Pygraphviz

Tags: python, graph, graphviz, pygraphviz

I am creating a .png file like this:

```
import pygraphviz as pgv

G = pgv.AGraph()
G.add_nodes("a")
G.add_edge("b", "c")

G.layout()
G.draw("output.png")
```

How can I set the size of the output image?

Comment: This may be of some use: http://www.graphviz.org/doc/FAQ.html#Q40

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the maximum size of your output image, by setting **size**, which is an attribute of the *graph object*. E.g.,

```
digraph "my_graph" {

     graph[ fontname = "Helvetica-Oblique",
            fontsize = 12,
            label = "some label",
            size = "7.75,10.25" ];

     node [ shape = polygon,
            sides = 4 ];
}
```

In this example, i've set the graph size to 7.75 x 10.25, which is the size you want, to ensure that your graph fits on an 8.5 x 11 inch sheet and also to ensure that it occupies all of the space on that sheet.

Comment: size only specifies the _max_ size of the graph...is there a way to specify the _exact_ size og the output?

Comment: Note that to change that attribute from within the python code, using `pygraphviz`, you can use the `AGraph`'s `graph_attr.update(attr=value)` method, eg., given your graph is `G`: `G.graph_attr.update(size="2,2")`. More info about available attributes here: http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html

Comment: How many pixels per inch does it provide? Update: Ah, there's also a DPI attribute you can set: http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#a:dpi

Answer (score 1):

You can easily set up the resolution with :

```
G.draw("file.png", args='-Gdpi=200', prog="dot")
```

Or since it's a graph attribute :

```
G.graph_attr['dpi'] = '200'
```

If you wish to avoid concerns regarding resolution, an alternative option is to export the file in a vector format such as `.svg`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting the size, you might want to enforce a particular aspect ratio too.

To set a ratio of 1:1.4 (width=1, height=1.4, i.e. that of an A4 page, approximately), you can do this (with a maximum dimension of 10 inches):

```
G.draw('output.png', args='-Gsize=10 -Gratio=1.4', prog='dot')
```

The format here is:

Graph arguments: `-G<arg>`; Node arguments: `-N<arg>`; Edge arguments: `-E<arg>`.

There's a list of arguments here:
https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/graphviz/dot.1.en.html

Hope that helps.